# C++ - Segmentation fault when returning a string

Tags: c++, string, segmentation-fault

I have this class

```
#include "Room.h"
#include "Book.h"
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

static int book_counter = 100;

//Constructors
Book::Book() {
    for(int i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
        this->customer_name += 97 + rand() % 26;
    }
    this->arrival = rand() % 30;
    this->duration = 1 + (rand() % 10);
    this->ppl = 1 + rand() % 5;
    this->room = nullptr;
    this->book_code = book_counter++;
}
Book::Book(std::string nm, int arr, int dur, int ppl) {
    this->customer_name = nm;
    this->arrival = arr;
    this->duration = dur;
    this->ppl = ppl;
    this->room = nullptr;
    this->book_code = book_counter++;
}

//Methods
int Book::getArr() {
    return arrival;
}
int Book::getDur() {
    return duration;
}
int Book::getPpl() {
    return ppl;
}
void Book::anathesi(Room* x) {
    this->room = x;
}
int Book::getBookCode() {
    return book_code;
}
Room* Book::getRoom() {
    return room;
}
std::string Book::getCustomerName() {
    return customer_name;
}
```

which includes a string getter method `getCustomerName()`.
When I call this method on main, via an instance created via the first constructor, everything works fine. On the other hand, if the instance is created via the second constructor, the method will cause a segmentation fault.

It seems like `customer_name` has an infinite length, thus causing a segmentation fault when I try to return it.

The method is called in `main` with this line of code:

```
cout << hotel.getBooks(i)->getBookCode() << " " << hotel.getBooks(i)->getCustomerName()
                             << " " << hotel.getBooks(i)->getRoom()->getRoomCode() << "\n";
```

I am new into C++, so please elaborate my fault as much as needed.

The header file for class Book:

```
#ifndef PROJECT_BOOK_H
#define PROJECT_BOOK_H
#include <string>

class Room;

class Book {
    protected:
        std::string customer_name;
        int book_code;
        int arrival;
        int duration;
        int ppl;
        Room* room;
    public:
        Book();
        Book(std::string nm, int arr, int dur, int ppl);
        void anathesi(Room* x);
        int getArr();
        int getDur();
        int getPpl();
        int getBookCode();
        std::string getCustomerName();
        Room* getRoom();
};

#endif //PROJECT_BOOK_H
```

In Hotel.h:

```
private: std::vector<Book*> books;
public: Book* getBooks(int i);
```

In Hotel.cpp:

```
Book* Hotel::getBooks(int i) {
    return books[i];
}
```

Comment: Can you show the definition of the class, and in particular of customer_name ?

Comment: Get rid of all of those uses of `this` - they are not necessary, make the code hard to read, and you don't even use them consistently.

Comment: @Christophe added the header

Comment: @NeilButterworth on the method `anathesi(Room* x)` too or just the constructors?

Comment: Are you sure that `hotel.getBooks(i)` returns a pointer to a valid `Book`?

Comment: @AQUATH Everywhere. It is almost never necessary to explicitly use `this`.

Comment: @UnholySheep I think yes. `hotel.getBooks(i)->getBookCode()` works fine on every case, whereas even `hotel.getBooks(i)->getCustomerName()` works fine when `customer_name` is created randomly.

Comment: Just because a C++ program crashed at a particular line doesn't mean that's where the bug is. There's nothing wrong with how the string is being returned. The bug can be anywhere, which is why a fully reproducible, [mcve] is required. Welcome to C++!

Comment: hotel.getBooks(i) certainly returns an invalid or a corrupted pointer. Both book constructors are ok.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik CLion's debugger highlighted this line. I can reproduce the problem when creating a Book instance using the second constructor and then trying to print this attribute.

Comment: Adding `getBooks(int i)` declaration/definition on OP..

Comment: All that a debugger tells you is where you program crashed. As I explained, that's not the same thing as "that's where the bug is". I can trivially write a recursive function that craps all over the stack, but returns fine, and the crash will occurs in the function's caller's caller, in some unrelated part of the code. That's where it will crash and that's where the debugger will show you the line is. But that's not where the bug is. It's great that you can reproduce the crash. But if you want someone else to figure it out for you, they'll have to do the same. Not possible, without a [mcve].

Comment: Your hotel.h will not compile. You're missing the body of a class from the looks of it. Don't waste your time posting only bits of the program or posting the entire program. Make a new program that replicates the bug and includes nothing that does not reproduce the bug. Once you've written that program, the [mcve], if you don't understand the bug and how to fix it, post the new program. Odds are really good that once you have distilled the problem down to its bare essentials you'll know how to fix it without any help.

Comment: I posted the answer below.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found the problem and fixed it.
I was creating instances with this piece of code:

```
Book obj(onoma, afiksh - 1, meres, arithmos);
```

which caused the segmentation I said.
I changed this to:

```
Book *obj = new Book(onoma, afiksh - 1, meres, arithmos);
```

and fixed the problem. Thanks for your time and help.
Unfortunately, I don't really know why this works, but it does, everything functions properly. Therefore I guess I'll have to look at `new` documentation.